# How do you make a "title bar" for a 3D touch peek view controller

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, peek-pop

Ideally, it should look like it does in Messages. Is there an API for this? If not, how would this be done manually?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your `UIViewController` inside `UINavigationController` before presenting via peek

Comment: This creates a way of displaying what I am looking for. However, it is not the same. It doesn't have that translucency that Apple seems to use with 3D touch UI items and the title isn't as big.

Comment: Since my question said that these requirements are only the ideal, I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you.